# Return to the calling page

Tags: asp.net

I have the following situation:
A “main” page displays GridView of items in the dataset.  User selects an item and clicks in the DataNavigateUrlFields which opens a new page in a new tab.  Let’s call this page DetailViewPage. User process the information on the DetailViewPage and clicks on button Done.   I want the page DetailViewPage to be closed/removed and focus (if such term exists in web application) return back to the GridView page and refresh the GridView Page.

How would I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.opener` to manipulate the window which opened the popup. Something like:

```
function closePopupAndRefreshParent() {
    window.opener.location.href = "" + window.opener.location.href;
    window.close();
}
```

Or any of the other dozens of ways of refreshing a page - I forget which is the most correct and browser-friendly...

Comment: I will explore this option as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a little more javascript and rely a little less on WebForms doing the work, you can do something a little different. Instead of a new window, you can have the click of an item open a new floating div or floating iframe, and from there, you have control over both the popup and the original window.

Comment: Joe, thank you for your suggestions.  I will have to explore the options of JS and new floating div or iframe. The applicaiton target is tablet browsers (e.g. iPad) so I am not sure how this approach will work there.  Need to test and try.  Again. thank you.